# Planning to use different size images across different devices

Tags: website-design, images, resize, image-format

The current framework I use to design webpages currently doesn't do anything to optimize images across different devices. As I see it, their are four types: mobile, tablet, desktop PC and large desktop PC to make things simple, the last three can be considered as one unit and mobile devices as a separate entity (I understand that they are not the same and shouldn't be considered in the same breath).

Dimensioning is the issue I'm having. If we consider a graphic for the header that will take up 100% of the width and be a height of 500px how is that graphic best translated down to a smaller device (iPhone 5 for argument's sake)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the header graphic is wider than it is taller, I would suggest having it follow the width of your target device. The header may have to be re-sized into a different dimension for mobile devices though.

My suggestion would be to enlarge the graphic height and optimize it to look best on a mobile device. For example, you could increase text size to increase readability on a mobile device. Also, try to export the graphic at 2x (150dpi) to ensure best results.

Comment: So it is a case of having two different sets of graphics?

Comment: Yes. You can then use media queries in your CSS to load different images for each screen size. You can refer to [this link](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) for more details.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.